# Django 'Key(field)=() is duplicated'

Tags: python, django, postgresql, wagtail

This question had been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162620/django-slugs-key-slug-is-duplicated), but for a different scenario.

I am working on a *Django/Wagtail* project. At some point I had to modify a model, and add some fields.

Accidentally I included a flag ***unique=True*** for a new field. This way:

```
title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=_('Category Title'))
```

When making migrations and migrating, it yelled this issue:

[image]

Then I realized the mistake, removed the ***unique=True*** and left it like this:

```
title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=_('Category Title'))
```

I made the migrations and migrated again, expecting the issue to go away. However I get the same issue.

How can I solve this?

This is the last migrations:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('distributed', '0029_remove_blogcategory_title'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='blogcategory',
            name='title',
            field=models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100, null=True, verbose_name='Category Title'),
        ),
    ]
```

And this is the trace:

```
    Microsoft Windows [Versión 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Reservados todos los derechos.

C:\Windows\system32>cd C:/

C:\>cd distributed

C:\distributed>cd distributed

C:\distributed\distributed>python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 6 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you
apply the migrations for app(s): distributed.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
April 26, 2017 - 12:40:45
Django version 1.10.7, using settings 'genesis.settings.dev'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
^C
C:\distributed\distributed>python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, distributed, otp_static, otp_
totp, otp_yubikey, sessions, sites, taggit, two_factor, wagtailadmin, wagtailcor
e, wagtaildocs, wagtailembeds, wagtailforms, wagtailimages, wagtailredirects, wa
gtailsearch, wagtailusers
Running migrations:
  Applying distributed.0025_auto_20170425_1827...Traceback (most recent call las
t):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 294,
 in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 345,
 in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py
", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 11
5, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_i
nitial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 14
5, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_
initial)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 24
4, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 1
29, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, projec
t_state)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py"
, line 84, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\schema.py",
line 21, in add_field
    super(DatabaseSchemaEditor, self).add_field(model, field)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 4
09, in add_field
    self.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 1
12, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in
execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cachalot\monkey_patch.py", line 111, in in
ner
    out = original(cursor, sql, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in
execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in
execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: could not create unique index "distributed_blogc
ategory_title_key"
DETAIL:  Key (title)=() is duplicated.


C:\distributed\distributed>
```

Comment: Just added them

Comment: The traceback is telling you that the error is occurring in `distributed.0025_auto_20170425_1827` - I don't think that's the migration you have shown. What is the output of `python manage.py showmigrations distributed`?

Comment: You are right. This is where my 'newbieness' is evident. I thought new migrations "overwrote" old ones. So, should I delete migrations up to the one causing the error and re run the make migrations?

Comment: **Wait before deleting any migrations**. If you delete migrations that have already been applied, it can be extremely difficult to get your models and database back into sync. Run `python manage.py showmigrations distributed` to see what migrations have been applied.

Comment: I never ran this before, however I can figure out, I think.  This is the result:
` [X] 0022_auto_20170109_1620`
` [X] 0023_auto_20170109_1621`
` [X] 0024_auto_20170112_1933`
` [ ] 0025_auto_20170425_1827`
` [ ] 0026_auto_20170425_1829`
` [ ] 0027_auto_20170425_1839`
` [ ] 0028_auto_20170425_1840`
` [ ] 0029_remove_blogcategory_title `
` [ ] 0030_blogcategory_title`

Comment: I assume, it shows number 24 was the last applied migration, so, it is save to delete up to 25, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If you delete 25-30 (or back them up to be safe), then run `makemigrations` and `migrate` then it should work.

Comment: It woked! Not sure if I can mark your comment as the correct answer directly, if not, and want to make it an official answer I will mark is as the correct one.

Comment: Glad it worked :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The traceback is telling you that the error occurs when you try to run migration 0025.

The output of `python manage.py showmigrations` tells you that migrations 0025-0030 have not been applied.

```
[X] 0022_auto_20170109_1620
[X] 0023_auto_20170109_1621
[X] 0024_auto_20170112_1933
[ ] 0025_auto_20170425_1827
[ ] 0026_auto_20170425_1829
[ ] 0027_auto_20170425_1839
[ ] 0028_auto_20170425_1840
[ ] 0029_remove_blogcategory_title
[ ] 0030_blogcategory_title
```

Therefore it should be safe to delete these migrations (you might want to back them up to be on the safe side). You can then rerun `makemigrations` and `migrate` to re-create and run new migrations.