# Django: Key (slug)=(*) already exists

Tags: python, django

I'm pretty new to Django and python and I'd like to learn more about how to populating my Postgres database.

Here is my current model: models.py

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

class Skill(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    slug = models.TextField(unique = True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % self.name
```

and my views: views.py

```
r = r.json()

try:
    Skills = r['data']['skills']
except:
    pass

for skill in Skills:
    skill = Skill.objects.create(name=skill['name'],slug=slugify(skill['name']))
```

I'm getting the error: 
Exception Type: IntegrityError

DETAIL:  Key (slug)=(systems-engineering) already exists.

I've been reading a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162620/django-slugs-key-slug-is-duplicated) although still haven't been able to solve my problem. objects.create() will shows an error when the object already exists in the database, but I was getting error with the code above. Could "unique = True" be causing the error? and how do you fix this?

Follow up

My problem is simpler than I thought. I was able to run `psql`  interactive terminal and see my data populating. I wasn't able to see it on the admin site because I missed out registering the models on admin.py

Comment: what's you content of `Skills` ?

Comment: "skills": [
            {
                "name": "systems engineering"
            },
            {
                "name": "consumer electronics"
            },
            {
                "name": "product development"
            }, ... ]

Comment: can you provide the full traceback of your error?

Comment: Here is my full [traceback](http://dpaste.com/10TCE11) Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you provide `unique=True`, the field will be unique throughout the table. Hence, when you try to add a data which is already in DB, it will raise an error. See this [official doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#unique) for more details

Comment: My problem is the data haven't been added and yet it recognizes the data as duplicate. I tried doing `try` & `except` although it never executes the objects.create

Comment: are you sure that it is never executed to the database? `objects.create()` always create an instance. You need to check it in your db if it really doesnt exist.

Comment: I looked into database and saw the objects now.!